# How do I create this type of node : <node />?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm using the `System.Xml` namespace of the .NET framework.
I know how to create a normal node with

```
Dim doc = new XmlDocument()
doc.createNode(xmlNodeType.Element, "node")
```

The result is : `<node>`
But I can't seem to find a way to create a node that is "self closed" (  )

Is it possible?

Comment: How do you call this type of node? Is it even a real Xml node type? Or is it bad practice to use those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there are specialized methods like `CreateElement` that create elements for you.

Second, the result of `CreateNode` (or `CreateElement`) is a node that is not attached to anything. You need to append it to the document.

```
Dim doc = new XmlDocument()
Dim element = doc.CreateElement("node")
doc.AppendChild(element)

Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml)
```

Then it prints, as you'd expect:

```xml
<node />
```

Note that it is not in any way bad practice for a node to be 'self closed'. In fact, when a node has no child nodes, you can write it in one of two ways:

```xml
<node></node>
<node />
```

And for all purposes and intents there is *no* difference between the two.

---

There is also the `XDocument` class and friends in the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace that are newer. You might find them easier to work with:

```
Dim doc = new XDocument()
doc.Add(new XElement("node"))

Console.WriteLine(doc)
```